# PyQt playing video repeat endless(using QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I created my VideoPlayer class and it works fine for play just one time.

But When I tried to play a video repeat many time(endless), it doesn't work. I called play() to `video_player.mediaPlayer.play()`, but they printed just black.

I think it is a QMediaPlaylist problem, but I can't find any problem.

```
 class VideoPlayer(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, video_path, parent=None):
    super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)
    self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

    videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(videoWidget)

    self.setLayout(layout)

    self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

    playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(video_path)))
    playlist.setCurrentIndex(1)
    playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.CurrentItemInLoop)
    self.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(playlist)
```

Code to playing just a time is `self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(video_path)))`. it works very well.

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: You can use single brackets (`\``) instead of `\`\`\`` for short code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many other Qt *objects*, if they don't have a parent nor a persistent reference, they just get deleted.

Your problem is that `playlist` is garbage collected as soon as the `__init__` returns, resulting in QMediaPlayer having no content left to play.

Make the playlist object a member of the instance, or create it with a parent (for example, the window):

```
    self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    # or
    playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self)
```

Comment: It is a very serious, but hard to find problem. After adopt your code, it works totally correctly.

Comment: @HansuKim the important thing to remember is that PyQt objects are just *references* to their C++ counterpart, so, sometimes, garbage collection might result unintuitive. For instance, a simple line as `QPushButton(self)` (without creating a reference to it, not even a local variable like `button = QPushButton()`) creates a button that is a child of `self` (the current widget instance, which acts as a *parent*): it appears "embedded" in the widget, and doesn't get deleted as soon as that parent widget exists; this is because creating QObjects with a parent also creates a persistent reference.

Comment: The same would have happened for QMediaPlayer: if you didn't make it a member of `self`, it wouldn't have worked even trying to directly play the file with `setMedia()`. On the contrary, if you had created the media player as a *local*, but **with** the parent (`mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(self, ...)`), it would have worked. A similar behavior can be observed for widgets added to layouts: even if they don't get a persistent reference, using `addWidget(...)` on a layout that is set on an existing widget will not delete them, since `addWidget()` automatically changes the ownership to the parent.

Comment: When uncertain, check the documentation: if you are using `someObject.setSomething(something)`, the documentation about that `setSomething` will tell you whether that `someObject` will take *ownership* of that `something` or not (if it's not specified, it usually doesn't). In this specific case, `setPlaylist` doesn't change the ownership of the playlist, and since QMediaPlayer is also an asynchronous object, that playlist will be deleted as soon as the `__init__` returns, thus "emptying" the contents for QMediaPlayer: when control gets back to the event queue, there's nothing left to play.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful to me. Especially your mention about `addWidget()`, I can find my code's another problem.